# Method that uses a button to convert requested data to different metric

Tags: javascript, jquery

At the moment, I have been able to request temperature from DarkSky's API, but degrees are in Fahrenheit when displayed on the user's screen. Consequently, I was wondering if could wrap my existing JS code with that button so that I could convert from Celsius to Fahrenheit and vise-versa? Perhaps I need to wrap the my temperature id in a button and use a function of some sort?

Here's my codepen: https://codepen.io/baquino1994/pen/ayJOod?editors=1011

HTML

```
<head>

  <meta name = "viewport" content ="width=device-width, intitial-scale = 1"/>
  <link rel = "stylesheet" href ="style.css"/>
  <link rel = "http://ipinfo.io"/>
  <title>Weather</title>
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Monoton" rel="stylesheet">
  <script src = https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js></script>
</head>



<body>
 <header>
   <h1><div id="minutely"></div></h1>
 <h2><div id="location"></div></h2>
 </header>
  <p><span id="city"</span></p>


  <p> <span id="country"></span></p>
  <div id="temp" id="tempunit"></div>
  <button class="btn btn-primary" id="BT1">Change Metric</button>

</body>
```

JS

```
function weather(){
    function success(position){
        var latitude = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude= position.coords.longitude;
        // location.innerHTML = "Latitude:" + latitude+"°"+ "Longitude: " + longitude+'°';
        var theUrl = url +apiKey + "/"+ latitude+","+ longitude +"?callback=?";

    $.getJSON(theUrl, function(data){
        $("#temp").html(data.currently.temperature)
      $("#minutely").html(data.minutely.summary)


  $.ajax({
      url:'', dataType: 'json',
     success: function(results){
         $("#city").text(results.results[3].address_components[4].long_name)
  $("#country").text(results.results[0].address_components[5].long_name)

     }


 }




    )}
             );
   }    


var location = document.getElementById("location");
var apiKey = "";
var url = "https://api.darksky.net/forecast/";
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);
// location.innerHTML = "Locating...";

   }
$(document).ready(function(){ 
weather();
 });
```

Comment: Note that $(weather) does work too instead of $(document...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wait on a button click, then convert:

```
var fahrenheit = true;
var FtoC = 0.01;//may look that up

var temp = $("#temp");

$("#BTN1").on("click",function(){

  var value = + temp.text() || 0;
  if(fahrenheit){
    temp.text(value * FtoC );
  }else{
    temp.text(value / FtoC );
  }
 fahrenheit =! fahrenheit;
});
```

You may need to reset the flag if the value gets updated. If you want to append the unit, thats easy too:

```
temp.append(fahrenheit ? "F" : "C");
```

Answer (score 1):

```
        function ctf(c){
        f=c*9/5+32;
        return f;
    }
    function ftc(f){
        c=f-32; 
        c*=(5/9);
        return c;
    }
f=1;
convert(){
if(f==0){
ctf(*temp*);
f=0;
}else{
ftc(*temp*);
f=1;
}
}
```

insert into html

```
<button onclick="convert()">Convert</button>
```